# Select max column from row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a query but I can't figure out how to do a certain operation.
I have a table where I am selecting individuals based  on their region, along with their age and four of their activities.

So I am selecting individuals grouped by region, average age and a sum of all the activity. with the goal of selecting the main activity out of the 
4. For a region. So my data is returned like

```
region  number   avgage   a1   a2  a3   a4  needed?
----------------------------------------------------
A        5       45       3    4    1   5     a4
B        4       23       1    8    2   6     a2
```

SQL

```
SELECT 
    C.gri,COUNT(A.ID) AS num,
    AVG(CONVERT(INT, ROUND(DATEDIFF(HOUR, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766.0, 0))) AS AveAge,
    SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male,
    SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female,
    SUM(CAST(a1 AS INT)) AS a1,
    SUM(CAST(a2 AS INT)) AS a2,
    SUM(CAST(a3 AS INT)) AS a3,
    SUM(CAST(a4 AS INT)) AS a4,
FROM
    profiile A
INNER JOIN 
    city B ON A.city = B.id
INNER JOIN 
    region C ON B.gri = C.id
GROUP BY 
    C.gri
```

What I am trying to accomplish is a way to retrieve the `needed` column.

Grateful for any assistance that could be provided.

Comment: In the `needed` column do you want the column name ("a4") or the value (5)?

Comment: @RazvanSocol Well bascially im trying to select the main activity from the region. So if a1 happens to have the most, i want to get that in the needed clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case statement

```
CASE
WHEN COALESCE(A1, 0) > COALESCE(A2, 0) AND COALESCE(A1, 0) > COALESCE(A3, 0) AND COALESCE(A1, 0) > COALESCE(A4, 0) THEN 'A1'
WHEN COALESCE(A2, 0) > COALESCE(A3, 0) AND COALESCE(A2, 0) > COALESCE(A4, 0) THEN 'A2'
WHEN COALESCE(A3, 0) > COALESCE(A4, 0) THEN 'A3'
ELSE 'A4' END AS MainActivity
```

If you don't have to worry about NULLs, then you can get rid of the coalesces. If there are multiple activities with the same count it will return the last activity having that max value

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *, x.ColumnName
FROM YourQuery
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 ColumnName
    FROM (
        SELECT 'a1' AS ColumnName, a1 AS TheValue
        UNION ALL SELECT 'a2', a2
        UNION ALL SELECT 'a3', a3
        UNION ALL SELECT 'a4', a4
    ) y
    ORDER BY TheValue DESC
) x
```

Comment: Not trying to order them , trying to select the max activity.